# Is there any way to create and open a file if it doesn't exist but fail otherwise?

Tags: rust

It looks like [`OpenOptions`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html) does not support this scenario and an existing file will either be truncated or overwritten.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As of Rust 1.9.0, there is [`OpenOptions::create_new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html#method.create_new) which enables you to safely and atomically ensure that you are creating a new file. An Err is returned if the file already exists. If `.create_new(true)` is set, `.create()` and `.truncate()` are ignored.

If you want to create a new file, or open it if it already exists, use [`OpenOptions::create`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html#method.create).

Comment: And as from 1.77, there's [`File::create_new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.create_new)

Answer (score 11):

I've found this to work best:

```
use std::fs;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io::prelude::*;

if Path::new(file).exists() {
  fs::remove_file(file).unwrap();
}

File::create(TMP_ADDS).unwrap();
    let mut file = OpenOptions::new()
        .create_new(true)
        .write(true)
        .append(true)
        .open(file)
        .unwrap();

    if let Err(e) = writeln!(file, "{}", line) {
        eprintln!("Couldn't write to file: {}", e);
    }
```

Comment: This is what [the accepted answer already states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44218350/155423); how does this answer differ?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible in C11, or by using low-level OS API functions directly.

If you use C11, [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) allows you to open the file in `"wx"` mode.

Otherwise, on Linux, one should pass both `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL` to the [`open(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open) function. Or, on Windows, pass `CREATE_NEW` to the `dwCreationDisposition` parameter of the [`CreateFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

---

**EDIT:** I originally missed the fact that the `open` function had been updated in C11.

Comment: Exclusive open mode was added in C11 actually. `fopen("wx")`

Comment: @bluss: Damned, my favorite reference (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) does not mention this `x` flag.

Comment: They have it right if you check their ***C*** reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen  :-)

Comment: @bluss: Oh! I guess it's worth opening a RFC to add a new OpenOptions then? I'll tweak the answer anyway.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: The `OpenFile` function on Windows exists for backwards compatibility only; `CreateFile` is the API to use nowadays, and it does provide a way to create a file only if it doesn't already exist. I've edited your answer with that information.

Comment: @FrancisGagné: Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** As Mathieu David pointed out in the comments. [`exists()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.exists) from
`std::path::Path` can be used to check if a path exists.

**Old Answer:**

> In C, checking if a file name/path exists is usually done with:
>
> ```
> ! access(filename, F_OK)
> ```
>
> `access` returns 0 if the file exists, provided that you have the needed permissions.
>
> I did a quick search for a native Rust equivalent and couldn't find anything. So, you may need to depend on [`libc::access`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/libc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libc/fn.access.html) for this.

Comment: Is it possible for a race condition to happen here, where the file comes into existence after `access` but before `open`?

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes. And I believe I saw Coverity Scan warning about this. But, what is the alternative?

Comment: Why would you need to use an unsafe function? You can check if a path exists with [`exists()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.exists) and then create the file if it doesn't.

Comment: @MathieuDavid I didn't know `exists()` exist ;)

Comment: It looks like there already an RFC to add this functionality: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1252-open-options.md#create_new

Comment: It looks like this is the best way for now although it introduces a race condition and a security concern.

Comment: Of course, it depends on one's reason, but the classic reason to want to do this is to create a lock file, and in that case avoiding races is the whole point.