# How can I read a file or create it along with its directory if it doesn't exist?

Tags: rust

I want to read a file into a vector, but if it doesn't exist, I don't want the program to panic. Instead, I want the file to be created (with empty contents). If the directory doesn't exist, I want it to be created, too.

How can I do this automatically in Rust?

This is my current code:

```
pub fn read(path: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let file = File::open(path).unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let mut history = Vec::new();
    for line in reader.lines() {
        history.push(line.unwrap());
    }
    history
}
```

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Is there any way to create and open a file if it doesn't exist but fail otherwise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35636742/155423); [How can I create a file and its parent directories using a single method in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59046312/155423) If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score 3):

Ingredients:

- Recursively create a directory: [`create_dir_all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.create_dir_all.html)
- Create files: [`File::create`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.create) or [`OpenOptions`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html)

If you do not want your program to panic, `unwrap` is not your friend, as it panics as soon as you call it on an `Err`. Now, given that file operations - generally speaking - could *always* go wrong, you must decide what to do if a file operation fails. Simply returning an empty `Vec` without any associated file?

Regarding this, [error handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html), in particular with [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) is a worthwhile read.